# Calculated field, SELECT based on 2 IDs

Tags: sql, calculated-columns

I have a table, named FacilityDatabaseConnection, like-so,
ID, FacilityID, DatabaseTypeID, ConnectionString

So given a FacilityID and DatabaseTypeID pair you'd get a ConnectionString.
Both Facility and DatabaseType Tables have "Name" Fields.
I would like to make a "Name" field in FacilityDatabaseConnection to do the following,

```
SELECT (dbo.Facility.Name+' - '+dbo.DatabaseType.Name) as Name
FROM dbo.FacilityDatabaseConnection
INNER JOIN dbo.Facility
 ON dbo.FacilityDatabaseConnection.FacilityID = dbo.Facility.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.DatabaseType
 ON dbo.FacilityDatabaseConnection.DatabaseTypeID = dbo.DatabaseType.ID
```

So that it returns "FacilityName - DatabaseType"

**This works as a query but is it possible to make this a field?**

---

I've tried,

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.FacilityDatabaseConnection
ADD Name AS (SELECT (dbo.Facility.Name+' - '+dbo.DatabaseType.Name) as Name
FROM dbo.FacilityDatabaseConnection
INNER JOIN dbo.Facility
 ON dbo.FacilityDatabaseConnection.FacilityID = dbo.Facility.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.DatabaseType
 ON dbo.FacilityDatabaseConnection.DatabaseTypeID = dbo.DatabaseType.ID) PERSISTED
```

Which gave me an error of "Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed."

Is there a way to achieve this or is such a calculated field not possible?

Comment: you'd have to use a view to produce a derived view like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is SQL Server, computed columns cannot reference other tables, so what you are suggesting is not possible.

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

You should use a view/function/stored procedure instead.

Comment: Okay, Side-Question then.
Would there be a benefit to doing a view/function/SP to do this versus just doing a query in my program versus just making a regular field and manually making it named that?

The only thing I can figure is the manual one would take more space but be quicker and allow for alternate naming patterns (which could be seen at good or bad depending).

Comment: Honestly I don't think it really matters what you do until you identify this query as the bottleneck causing performance problems. However I would advise against prematurely denormalizing your database (and adding an extra column that you manually populate with data that already exists) because it will create a management and data integrity nightmare.

Comment: Yeah, I was/am avoiding that. We originally had the Name field there until I noticed we were using it only for this purpose so I deleted it, then I thought I might be able to do a calculated one. Honestly though it doesn't really seem important at all, so I'm thinking best option might be just to leave it gone and use the other data through code instead of SQL.

Answer (score 1):

There is a secret way to make computed column access another table.

That is to create a user-defined function that defines the field.  The UDF can then access the other table.

The alter statement looks something like:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.FacilityDatabaseConnection
    ADD Name AS udf_getFacilityName(FacilityId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
SELECT
    (SELECT count(*) FROM table1) as new_column_name,
    col1,
    col2
FROM
    table2
```